Why couldn't I see my cube, and why is my mouse cursor acting weird?
void App::onCreate()
{
    Window::onCreate();

    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard; // Enable Keyboard Controls
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableGamepad;  // Enable Gamepad Controls

    // Creating device and device context
    if (!graphicsEngine.createDevices(hwnd, 1280, 720)) {
        throw std::exception("Failed to create Direct3D device and swap chain");
    }

    g_pd3dDevice = graphicsEngine.device;
    g_pd3dDeviceContext = graphicsEngine.deviceContext;
    g_pSwapChain = graphicsEngine.swapChain->getSwapChain();
    graphicsEngine.swapChain->createRenderTargetView();
    g_mainRenderTargetView = graphicsEngine.swapChain->getRenderTargetView();
    depth_stencil_view = graphicsEngine.depth_view;

    // Ensure deviceContext is assigned correctly
    deviceContext = new DeviceContext(g_pd3dDeviceContext);
    if (deviceContext == nullptr) {
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("deviceContext is nullptr after creating devices");
    }

    // Load compiled vertex shader
    std::vector<char> vsBytecode = LoadShader(L"VertexShader.cso");
    vertex_shader = new VertexShader(vsBytecode.data(), vsBytecode.size(), g_pd3dDevice);
    // Load compiled pixel shader
    std::vector<char> psBytecode = LoadShader(L"PixelShader.cso");
    pixel_shader = new PixelShader(psBytecode.data(), psBytecode.size(), g_pd3dDevice);

    // Create vertex buffer
    try {
        vertex_buffer = new VertexBuffer(vertices, sizeof(Vertex), ARRAYSIZE(vertices), vsBytecode.data(), vsBytecode.size(), g_pd3dDevice);
        if (vertex_buffer == nullptr) {
            IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Vertex buffer is nullptr after creation");
        }
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Vertex buffer created successfully");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Failed to create Vertex buffer: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }

    // Create index buffer
    try {
        index_buffer = new IndexBuffer(indices, ARRAYSIZE(indices), g_pd3dDevice);
        if (index_buffer == nullptr) {
            IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Index buffer is nullptr after creation");
        }
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Index buffer created successfully");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Failed to create Index buffer: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }

    // Set the buffers in the device context
    try {
        deviceContext->setVertexBuffer(vertex_buffer);
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Vertex buffer set successfully");
        deviceContext->setIndexBuffer(index_buffer);
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Index buffer set successfully");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        IMGUI_DEBUG_LOG("Failed to set Vertex and Index buffers: %s", e.what());
    }
    //create the constant buffer
    Constant c;
    constant_buffer = new ConstantBuffer(&c, sizeof(Constant), g_pd3dDevice);
    deviceContext->setConstantBuffer(vertex_shader, constant_buffer);
    deviceContext->setConstantBuffer(pixel_shader, constant_buffer);

    // Setup Platform/Renderer backends
    if (!ImGui_ImplWin32_Init(hwnd)) {
        throw std::exception("Failed to initialize ImGui Win32 backend");
    }

    if (!ImGui_ImplDX11_Init(g_pd3dDevice, g_pd3dDeviceContext)) {
        throw std::exception("Failed to initialize ImGui DX11 backend");
    }


    deviceContext->clearRenderTargetColor(graphicsEngine.swapChain, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.75f, 1.0f);
    deviceContext->clearDepthStencilView(depth_stencil_view);
    g_pd3dDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_mainRenderTargetView, depth_stencil_view);
    deviceContext->setViewportSize(1280, 720);
    deviceContext->setVertexShader(vertex_shader);
    deviceContext->setPixelShader(pixel_shader);
    deviceContext->setVertexBuffer(vertex_buffer);
    deviceContext->setIndexBuffer(index_buffer);
    // Create view and perspective matrices
    CreateViewAndPerspective();

    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&rasterDesc, sizeof(rasterDesc));
    rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    ID3D11RasterizerState* rasterState;
    g_pd3dDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &rasterState);
    g_pd3dDeviceContext->RSSetState(rasterState);
}

void App::onUpdate()
{
    // (Your code process and dispatch Win32 messages)
    // Start the Dear ImGui frame
    ImGui_ImplDX11_NewFrame();
    ImGui_ImplWin32_NewFrame();
    ImGui::NewFrame();
    ImGui::ShowDemoWindow(); // Show demo window! :)
    // Rendering
    render();
    
    // (Your code clears your framebuffer, renders your other stuff etc.)
    
    // Update the model transformation
    updateModel();
}

void App::onDestroy()
{
    ImGui_ImplDX11_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplWin32_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    if (vertex_buffer) {
        delete vertex_buffer;
    }
    if (index_buffer) {
        delete index_buffer;
    }

    if (vertex_shader) {
        delete vertex_shader;
    }
    if (pixel_shader) {
        delete pixel_shader;
    }

    graphicsEngine.release();

    Window::onDestroy();
}


void App::render() {
    DirectX::XMMATRIX g_Player;
    // Initialize the world matrix
    g_Player = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();
    DirectX::XMMATRIX mRotate = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationZ(m_rot_z);
    DirectX::XMMATRIX mTranslate = DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    DirectX::XMMATRIX mScale = DirectX::XMMatrixScaling(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
    g_Player = mScale * mRotate * mTranslate;

    // Combine with view and projection matrices
    DirectX::XMMATRIX viewMatrix = DirectX::XMLoadFloat4x4(&view); // Load view matrix
    DirectX::XMMATRIX projMatrix = DirectX::XMLoadFloat4x4(&proj); // Load projection matrix
    DirectX::XMMATRIX worldViewProjMatrix = g_Player * viewMatrix * projMatrix; // Combine matrices

    Constant cb1;
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&cb1.worldViewProj, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(worldViewProjMatrix));
    constant_buffer->update(deviceContext, &cb1);

    deviceContext->setConstantBuffer(vertex_shader, constant_buffer);
    deviceContext->setConstantBuffer(pixel_shader, constant_buffer);

    deviceContext->drawIndexedTriangleList(ARRAYSIZE(indices), 0, 0);

    // Render ImGui UI
    ImGui::Render();
    ImGui_ImplDX11_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

    g_pSwapChain->Present(1, 0);
}
void App::updateModel() {
    // Rotate the cube 1 degree per frame.
    Constant cb;
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(
        &cb.worldViewProj,
        DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(
            DirectX::XMMatrixRotationY(
                DirectX::XMConvertToRadians(
                    (float)m_frame++
                )
            )
        )
    );
    if (m_frame == MAXUINT)  m_frame = 0;
}
void App::CreateViewAndPerspective()
{
    // Use DirectXMath to create view and perspective matrices.
    DirectX::XMVECTOR eye = DirectX::XMVectorSet(-2.0f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 0.0f);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR at = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, -0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR up = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    DirectX::XMMATRIX viewMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtRH(eye, at, up);
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&view, viewMatrix);

    float aspectRatio = 1280.0f / 720.0f;
    DirectX::XMMATRIX projMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovRH(DirectX::XM_PIDIV4, aspectRatio, 0.01f, 100.0f);
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&proj, projMatrix);
}

I'm trying to render a cube alongside the ImGUI demo window. I've been at this for two days and I honestly lost the ability to think clearly about what I'm missing.
Here's the App.h necessary content:
#pragma once

class App : public Window
{
public:
    App();
    ~App();
    // Inherited via Window
    virtual void onCreate() override;
    virtual void onUpdate() override;
    virtual void onDestroy() override;
    virtual void onFocus() override;
    virtual void onKillFocus() override;
    virtual void onSize() override;
public:
    void render();
    void update();
    void updateModel();
    void updateCamera();
    void updateSkybox();
    void CreateViewAndPerspective();
private:
    GraphicsEngine graphicsEngine;
    IDXGISwapChain* g_pSwapChain = nullptr;
    ID3D11Device* g_pd3dDevice = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* g_pd3dDeviceContext = nullptr;
    ID3D11Buffer* dx_index_buffer = nullptr;
    ID3D11Buffer* dx_vertex_buffer = nullptr;
    ID3D11Buffer* dx_constant_buffer = nullptr;
    ID3D11InputLayout* vertexLayout = nullptr;
    ID3D11DepthStencilView* depth_stencil_view = nullptr;
private:
    SwapChain* swapChain = nullptr;
    DeviceContext* deviceContext = nullptr;
    const IndexBuffer* index_buffer = nullptr;
    const VertexBuffer* vertex_buffer = nullptr;
    ConstantBuffer* constant_buffer = nullptr;
    VertexShader* vertex_shader = nullptr;
    PixelShader* pixel_shader = nullptr;
private:


    UINT g_ResizeWidth = 0, g_ResizeHeight = 0;

    ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_mainRenderTargetView = nullptr;
private:

    UINT m_frame = 0;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 view = {};
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 proj = {};

    float m_rot_x = 0.0f;
    float m_rot_y = 0.0f;
    float m_rot_z = 0.0f;
};

What happened was: The App window is showing properly, but:

frames are acting weird, I cannot control my window properly because mouse cursor is acting strange

cube isn't shown at all


After toying with the Graphics Debugger, I saw that the cube vertices are indeed drawn, but that's it, no color and no rotation animation.
